# Do I need to use a webservice to do "Ajax" with JQuery to get my data in JSON format

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Do I need to use a webservice to do "Ajax" with JQuery to get my data in JSON format ? Colleagues recommend me to use a "Httphandler" ...  Finally, I wonder if I can't directly call a method in DataAccessLayer and pass it to Ajax ...

I'm lost, please can someone explain me **if I really need a Webservice to do Ajax with JQuery** ? There is **only ONE server (no remote server)**, so may be I don't need webservices ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a seperate web service. You can actually do AJAX on the same page. I'm a little rusty on this so bear with me, but all you do is:

1. Add a ToolkitScriptManager from the AJAX Control Toolkit
2. In your HTML, add this just after the form tag `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>`
3. Add the `[ScriptService]` attribute to your page class declaration
4. Add a `[ScriptMethod]` attribute to your method you wish to call. By default it transmits as JSON but you can respond with XML by using `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]`
5. This method needs to be static, because it should be executed without re-running the page render cycle.
6. Now you just need some jQuery to call the function

```cs
[ScriptService]
public class MyPage : Page
{
   [ScriptMethod]
   public static string GetText() { return "Hello, world!"; }
}
```

```html
<html>
<!-- jQuery scripts -->
<body>
<script language="javascript">
   $.ready(function () {

   var text = PageMethods.GetText();
   $("#label1").value(text);
   });
</script>
<form runat="server">

  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ha! Cool! had no even a though that page may be a scriptservice. Thanks for pointing on this!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. All you need to do is

- send the correct content-type in the header "application/json"
- re-arrange the server side output to return a JSON string representation of your actual output

Answer (score 0):

You can call regular .aspx (I know about HttpHandler in asp.net) page with AJAX. But in that case you are doing a lot of additional work (you must stop regular flow of page execution, ensure that you do not return some garbage, convert response into JSON etc.)  At the same time  -webservice does not require all that infrastructure needed for regular pages (in asp.net) and will not produce additional load on your server. The same about HttpHandler. You are doing only what you need and nothing else.